# Swift 3 and Alamofire 4.5, nested objects issues

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

My issue is this I have an app that is using Alamofire for REST business, and normaly is fine with the post and get actions. But in one method I need to send a complex object which was getting set to null the I changed some and it kind of worked, but not entirely. Here take a look at what I mean:

```
import UIKit
import ObjectMapper

open class CashSale: Sale, CustomStringConvertible {
    open var paymentCurrencyType: CurrencyType!
    open var changeCurrencyType: CurrencyType!
    open var amountReceived: Float!
    lazy open var jsonObject: [String:Any] = [:]

    public init (paymenttype:CurrencyType, changetype:CurrencyType, amount:Float, sale:Sale)
{
    super.init(dateTime: sale.dateTime, guid: sale.guid, saledescription: sale.factPaymentType, amount:sale.amount, saleStatus: sale.saleStatus, paymentType: sale.paymentType, employee: sale.employee, soldItems: sale.soldItems, pump: sale.pump , gasSaleType: sale.gasSaleType)

    self.amountReceived = amount
    self.changeCurrencyType = changetype
    self.paymentCurrencyType = paymenttype
    self.finishJson()
}

func finishJson() {



            jsonObject["paymentCurrencyType"] = paymentCurrencyType
            jsonObject["changeCurrencyType"] = changeCurrencyType
            jsonObject["amountReceived"] = amountReceived
            jsonObject["devicename"] = devicename
            jsonObject["id"] = id
            jsonObject["dateTime"] = (self.dateTime == "") ? "2017-08-10":self.dateTime
            jsonObject["guid"] = guid
            jsonObject["factPaymentType"] = factPaymentType
            jsonObject["amount"] = amount
            jsonObject["saleStatus"] = saleStatus
            jsonObject["paymentType"] = paymentType
            jsonObject["employee"] = ["id":self.employee.id, "name":self.employee.name, "pin": self.employee.pin, "employeeType": self.employee.employeeType, "pumps": self.employee.pumps]
           jsonObject["gasSaleType"] = gasSaleType
            jsonObject["soldItems"] = ["id":self.soldItems[0].id, "saleItem":["id":self.soldItems[0].saleItem.id, "itemType":self.soldItems[0].saleItem.itemType, "pricePerUnit":self.soldItems[0].saleItem.pricePerUnit, "barcode":self.soldItems[0].saleItem.barcode ?? "-1"], "quantity":self.soldItems[0].quantity, "localidadId":self.soldItems[0].localidadId]
            jsonObject["pump"] = ["id": self.pump.id, "status": self.pump.status, "gasTypes":self.pump.gasTypes]
            jsonObject["special"] = special
            jsonObject["invoiceDat"] = ["accountNum":(self.invoiceDat.accountNum == "" || self.invoiceDat.accountNum == nil) ? "-1":self.invoiceDat.accountNum!, "clientId":(self.invoiceDat.clientId == "" || self.invoiceDat.clientId == nil) ? "-1":self.invoiceDat.clientId!]
            jsonObject["finishType"] = finishType
}
}
```

And the call is here:

```
//Mensaje que manda una CashSale
    open func SendCashVenta(_ venta:CashSale, ip:String,  callBack:(()->Void)?, incorrecto:((_ Title:String, _ Error:String)->Void)?)
    {
        venta.devicename = DeviceName
        venta.invoiceDat = InvoiceData(accountnum: "", clientid: "")
        let address:String = "http://\(ip)/api/InitCashSales"
        let debugMsg = "Cash sale initiated"
        print(venta.jsonObject)      
        let serial =  JSONSerializer.toJson(venta)
//        let _parametros = JSONSerializer.toDictionary(serial) as! Parameters

        //debugPrint(_parametros)
        self.alamoFireManager!.request(address, method: .post, parameters: venta.jsonObject, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody)
            .responseJSON { response in
                self.responseEmptyCallback(response, result: response.result, callBack: callBack, incorrecto: incorrecto, debugMsg: debugMsg)
        }
    }
```

In the employee object the nesting works ok, taking the values and sending to the REST, but with the soldItems that is an array of objects with a nested array it sends nothing and my REST class crashes. So My question is how can i jsonify an object with more nested objects? Like mine. Thanks.

Comment: after the super.init() call .. does soldItems has the array set? please debug

Comment: Yes I have debugged right now and it is filled :)